# Sinch verification error 42202

Tags: android, sinch

I have integrated sinch verification in my application

```
Config config = SinchVerification.config().applicationKey(APP_KEY).context(getApplicationContext()).build();
            Verification verification = SinchVerification.createSmsVerification(config, "phone number", listener);
            verification.initiate();
```

But it is always showing **Invalid callback response.** error.

```
com.sinch.verification.ServiceErrorException: Sinch backend request failed with code: 42202 message: Invalid callback response.
at com.sinch.verification.internal.apiservice.ApiService.extractError(ApiService.java:95)
at com.sinch.verification.internal.apiservice.ApiService.handleResponse(ApiService.java:81)
at com.sinch.verification.internal.apiservice.ApiService.access$000(ApiService.java:13)
at com.sinch.verification.internal.apiservice.ApiService$1.onSuccess(ApiService.java:42)
```

I have already entered callback url in sinch application at developer site.

Answer (score 1):

If you configure a call back you need to respond with the correct format,ie 
content-type:application/json

```
{
    "action": "allow"
}
```

if you dont want a callback simply remove it. https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/rest/#verificationcallbackapi

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am using it in android, and i guess you are talking about rest api.

Comment: IF configured a callback URL in the portal IT still Apples. To use only  android only remove the callback URL.

Comment: If this answered you question can you mark it as answered please.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue in iOS. And I resolved by just removing Callback URL from Verification tab from your app listed in your account.

You can find it from https://portal.sinch.com/#/apps

Just remove Callback URL from that Verification tab and try again. I hope you will succeed.